# Chrome crashing with open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: chrome, crash

When I open Chrome, with a Python module named subprocess, it crashes and gives me these errors:

```
[1103/163807.480539:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[1103/163807.480673:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
```

Here are my arguments

```
google-chrome --disable-gpu \
              --start-maximized \
              --new-window \
              -incognito http://localhost:9932/
```

OS: Ubuntu 21.10 x86_64
User : root
Chrome Version : Chrome crashes when i open it

Comment: Please [edit] and state the OS and version and Chrome version.

Comment: Hi this question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70069412/error-installing-chrome-on-aws-ec2-linux-instance-scaling-cur-freq-scaling-ma/70113555#70113555

Comment: /usr/bin/microsoft-edge-stable on fedora-37 yields this same error this morning, April 22, 2023.

Comment: I have to ask the obvious question here: Is it possible that the directory doesn't exist because you don't have [CPU Frequency Scaling Enabled In the kernel](https://www.maketecheasier.com/how-to-control-your-cpu-frequency-in-ubuntu/) and this [very in-depth article from the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/CPU_frequency_scaling).  This directory is created by the kernel at boot time .